# Big payout from a bankrupt stock?

Tags: stocks, argentina

I had a small position in this Argentinian utility company (Metrogas, MGS) when it suddenly declared bankruptcy. That was about 10 years ago. I still had that position with a $0 value on my account until last year. Then all of a sudden, the position was closed and I got paid $10k from some corporate action. That was the only explanation on the brokerage statement. Obviously, I didn't call to clarify :) But I am still curious what might have happened.

Comment: Some lawsuit was resolved, I'd bet.  If you're in Argentina, Google it and tell us the results.

Comment: Maybe, but I got paid 10x what I had lost. I am in the US. MGS was an ADR stock.